# How to put the text above line in Tradingview API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tradingview-api

i tried to add a text above each of lines that i added in chart

i used the AddLineSeries method to draw a line from datas i have but i couldn`t any property for this
text above the line
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlnZo.jpg)
if somebody used this method and can give me the property for putting text above the line please let me know